# Django look css images into wrong directory

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have following settings for static files

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_my_proj'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'static_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'media_root')
```

In the css file I do this

```
#mydiv{
    background-image:  url('/img/myimg.png');
}
```

And my directory structure

```
project root
 - static_my_proj
  - css
  - img
  - js
```

I can see from network tab that it looks for the image in `static/css/img/myimg.png`. However, if I do this then it works. How can I make it without using `../` at the beginning?

```
#mydiv{
    background-image:  url('../img/myimg.png');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `/static/img/myimg.png`?

Comment: There is a slight advantage to using relative paths in your CSS - if you change your static files settings then you will not need to change any of the image paths

Comment: @IainShelvington `/static/img/myimg.png` seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You better use `{% static 'img/myimg.png %}`. Hardcoded paths aren't good, because if you change your static folder, you would have to change all your code. You can't use `static` in your css files, but in your templates. Your code would look like this:

yourHTML.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<div id="mydiv" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/myimg.png' %})">

</div>
```

Comment: I would avoid using inline styles in html.

Comment: You can also use a `style` tag. If then, I would recommend you using `django-sekizai` to make sure your code is only once in your template.